# Having a class as an @Input or property in a component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have several components in my Angular which inherit from a `BaseComponent`. In this  `BaseComponent` I have an `@Input` (or a property) called `filter` which is a class with several properties like `key`, `status` and `page`, so it is something like below:

```
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() autoload: boolean;
  @Output() dataLoaded: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  public filter : APIFilter
//simplified


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute ) {
    this.filter= new APIFilter()
   }
```

And my `APIFilter` class is something like below:

```
export class APIFilter {
  status: number[]=[];
  state: string | undefined;
  endDateYesterday: boolean = true;
  startDate: string| undefined;
  endDate: string | undefined;
  period: number | undefined;
  key: string;
  //simplified
  }
```

What I wanted to do was to have something like:

```
<app-component-inherited-from-base filter.key='someKey' filter.page='somePage'></app-component-inherited-from-base>
```

But no matter how I declare, so far, my `filter` property isn't changed and I can't use it in the inherited component because it doesn't register the new values.

Any ideas?

Comment: If `filter` is an input, why isn't there an `@Input() filter: APIFilter` declaration there.  You're insantiating a new filter there.  Sounds like you want to declare your filters in the parent component, and when you update the values use an `Output() EventEmitter` to notifiy the parent to update values and pass those values back down to child

Comment: Changing to `@Input()` is just a question of changing the base component. My problem isn't changing things at runtime, which works ok, it is the basic declaration of the starting values of the filter when I'm placing the components to my page, which aren't 'seen' by the child component nor the `BaseComponent`. The child component has the filter, but it doens't get the values declared on the html

Comment: @PauloWeber, Do you mean to pass the `filter` from Base to child component? If Yes, you can do so using @Input

Comment: why not use < app-component-inherited-from-base filter="{key:'somekey',page:'somePage'}" > ?